# Wavefront OBJ Parsing - why do I keep getting incorrect data as output?

Tags: c++, linux, parsing, opengl, mesh

I'm writing a Wavefront .OBJ mesh parser. While I've been working on this for about 3 weeks now, I decided to rewrite the majority of it, since I was parsing it character-by-character (which I felt was introducing too much complication, in the end, and wasn't working properly anyway). Now that I've been parsing it line-by-line, I feel like I'm getting worse results.

Here's an example of my output:

```
( STREAM ):# cube.obj


}

(LINE 2){

( STREAM ):#


}

(LINE 3){

( STREAM ): 


}

(LINE 4){

( STREAM ):g cube


}

(LINE 5){

( STREAM ): 


}

(LINE 6){

( VERTEX: 1 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 0.0 0.0 0.0


}

(LINE 7){

( VERTEX: 2 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 0.0 0.0 1.0


}

(LINE 8){

( VERTEX: 3 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 0.0 1.0 0.0


}

(LINE 9){

( VERTEX: 4 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 0.0 1.0 1.0


}

(LINE 10){

( VERTEX: 5 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 1.0 0.0 0.0


}

(LINE 11){

( VERTEX: 6 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 1.0 0.0 1.0


}

(LINE 12){

( VERTEX: 7 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 1.0 1.0 0.0


}

(LINE 13){

( VERTEX: 8 )'-597028128851671121920.000000 0.000000 -597118763794171953152.000000'

( STREAM ):v 1.0 1.0 1.0


}
```

---

I'm not working on parsing the indices currently (which are the lines which begin with `f`), just for the sake of simplicity.

**What I've tried so far (for vertex data)**

- `strtof( pLine, &pLine )`: this produced zeros for the vertices
- `current implementation within the following code`: not producing zeros, but definitely not the actual data stored

**Code**

```
   //...declare lineCount and vertexCount above
   // NOTE: BUFF_LEN == 200

    while( !feof( filePtr ) )
    {
        printf( "(LINE %i){\n\n", lineCount );

        fgets( line, BUFF_LEN, filePtr );


        // append NULL term, since fgets does not
        // return one.

        line[ BUFF_LEN - 1 ] = '\0';

        // evaluate the first character
        switch( line[ 0 ] )
        {
            case 'v':
            {
                if ( line[ 1 ] == ' ' )
                {
                    // we have a vertex, not a normal

                    SIMD_VEC3 v;

                    fscanf( filePtr, " %f %f %f\n", &v[ 0 ], &v[ 1 ], &v[ 2 ] );

                    printf( "( %i )\'%f %f %f\'\n\n",
                            vertexCount, v[ 0 ], v[ 1 ], v[ 2 ] );

                    ++vertexCount;
                }
            }
                break;
        }
    //...printf out the current line parsed from fgets, increment line count
    }
```

I'm working in C++, but am looking for a standard C approach. I also am working with OpenGL and Linux, though I'm not sure that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand:

1. You take a line into a buffer - `fgets( line, BUFF_LEN, filePtr );`
2. but then you use `fscanf` to read values for the vector... you use `filepointer`

I think you should use `sscanf` to read from the `line` buffer.

After the fist step file pointer is moved so when you use second step you are reading some different data from the file.

In general reading from a file involves:

- read one line into some buffer
- parse that buffer (that line)
- read another line

some more info [opengl totorial about OBJ](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Load_OBJ), [OBJ loader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/objloader/)